# RDP connection broken when closing lid

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce, xrdp

I have old Acer Aspire that I want to turn in home server and connect remotely.
I installed Linux Mint (XFCE edition because I wanted something lightweight).
XRDP is installed and everything works fine until I close the lid.
When I do that RDP connection is down and laptop looks like it's sleeping. I've tried every option in "Power Manager" and none is working. Is there anything to prevent that? Ideal would be to turn off screen on closing, but anything that works would be fine.

Comment: It may be a lot easier just to leave the lid open. That is why I do. There may be.BIOS setting to close the lid with No Action but watch for overheating

Comment: It might be enough to place a thick metallic wire segment to leave the lid open enough for the lid sensor not to be activated.